# How to use one installation for MULTIPLE sites?

Tags: multisite, single

My question is something different. I have several Wordpress Installations in my localhost:

```
localhost/1
localhost/2
localhost/3
... etc...
```

I want them all to use one wordpress installation folder (except `wp-content` - I want each site had its own `wp-content`).

I dont want to use Multi-Site feature (because each `1`,`2` and etc sites are separate Multi-site installations themselves).
So, what should I do?

I want to use only 3 files in each subdirectory, i.e.

```
localhost/1/index.php
localhost/1/.htaccess
localhost/1/wp-content
```

and they use one predefined WP-CORE folder, from i.e.

```
localhost/wpcore/wp-admin
localhost/wpcore/wp-includes
localhost/wpcore/wp-login.php
...etc..
```

how to achieve that? Maybe some `htaccess` and `wp-config` tricks will be needed?

Comment: You can use symbolic links but you have to make sure they all have the right permissions to read and write to the shared folders

Comment: You could use Multisite and add [the WP Multi Network plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/), which (apparently) allows for a network of networks.

Comment: Using the same installation to develop separate sites is a very, very bad idea. How do you test upgrades? Use Vagrant, Docker or something similar instead.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257718/setup-multi-multi-site-with-one-installation/348957#348957