# setup Multi Multi-site with one installation?

Tags: multisite

There are `wp_blogs` and `wp_site` tables, which seem, are preserved for ability to contain more than 1 main_site....

so, how can we make Multiple Multi-site?  (as each of them were like main-site itself, with it's sub-sites...)

Comment: What will be your reason for a *Multiple Multisite*? Can you please elaborate a give a scenario with sitemaps as an edit to your post?

Comment: there should not be a problem doing that, and there are plugins for it. Not sure if core already has UI to control it, but it is supported in the API IIRC

Comment: [WP Multi Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/)

Comment: Found answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16934/can-i-run-a-second-wordpress-site-as-a-subdomain-without-using-multisite

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with using such solution:

1) Created folders like:

```
wp-base
- wp-admin
- wp-includes
- .... all wp-php files
```

and I've created "[symlink](https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/)" that 2-folder and wp standard php files inside other folders:

```
my-wp-1
- wp-content & wp.config.php & htaccess
my-wp-2
- wp-content & wp.config.php & htaccess
```

The only thing I had to do is to use this in the top of `wp-load.php`:

```
$fold=filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], SANITIZE_STRING);
/** Define ABSPATH as this file's directory */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname( __FILE__ )). "/$fold/" );
}
```

There seems no need of adding  `define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', __DIR__.'/wp-content' );` in wp-config.